# Sinatra script not working

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am new to Ruby and just want a web page which would find prime numbers and print. That's it. I want to do it with Sinatra framework. Here's my code:

```
#require 'prime'
require 'sinatra'

def primes(size)
    arr=(0..size).to_a
    arr[0]=nil
    arr[1]=nil
    max=size
    (size/2+1).times do |n|
        if(arr[n]!=nil) then
            cnt=2*n
            while cnt <= max do
                arr[cnt]=nil
                cnt+=n
            end
        end
    end
    arr.compact!
end

set :port, 8080
set :static, true
set :public_folder, "static"
set :views, "views"

get '/' do
    #return 'Hello world'
    return puts primes(10)
end
```

I run this script via `http://localhost:8080/` and I see nothing. Just a blank page. The Hello World with same script works fine. The `primes` function also works perfect which I have tested via command line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the line `return puts primes(10)`.

`puts` just puts an output to STDOUT (the console) and not the HTTP response (content of the webpage). Also I still think it would be an issue to return an array to Sinatra since it uses arrays for passing additional data about a response, so if you want to test this script out it will probably work if you change the mentioned line to:

> primes(10).to_s

`to_s` converts your array into a string.

Comment: Or `return primes(10).to_s` would also work, but it doesn't matter since implicit return already takes place in the example.